# how to display html form using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have a form to enter the skills of an employee and below the form there is a link to add new skill.when clicking on the link the form has to be display again.

i have written code like this

```
             <html>
             <head>
             <script type="text/javascript">
         function newStyle()
         {
         document.getElementById('add').innerHTML="<html><body><table>  
         <tr>
     <td>Skill</td><td><select name="skill">
             <option>Select</option>
             </select></td>
     <td>percentage of knowledge</td>
     <td><input type="number" name="percentage" min="1" max="100"/></td>
     <td>No of years experience</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="no_years_experience"></td>
     <td>Highest level </td><td><select name="highest_level">
             <option>Select</option>
             </select></td>
         </tr>
         </table>
     </body></html>";
             }
             </script>
             </head>
             <body>
             <table>    
         <tr>
     <td>Skill</td><td><select name="skill">
             <option>Select</option>
             </select></td>
     <td>percentage of knowledge</td>
     <td><input type="number" name="percentage" min="1" max="100"/></td>
     <td>No of years experience</td>
     <td><input type="text" name="no_years_experience"></td>
     <td>Highest level </td><td><select name="highest_level">
             <option>Select</option>
             </select></td>
         </tr>
        </table>
    <a onclick="newStyle()" >Add New Skill</a>
            <div id="add"></div>
            </body> 
            </html>
```

here the form do not display when i click the Add new skill .Can anybody help me to display the form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the following issues

1. JS Strings cannot have newlines. Although it is possible to change all newlines to nothing or escape the newline with \ it is not recommended and in here not necessary as you will see
2. If your string contains double quotes, you need to wrap it in single quotes or escape the double quotes `\"` but in your case we can simply clone your table

I gave your table an ID and the anchor an href and ID too

**Plain JavaScript version** - expects the source table to be wrapped in a container

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/2P889/)

```
window.onload=function() {
  var srcTable = document.getElementById("srcDiv").innerHTML;
  document.getElementById("addBut").onclick=function() {
    document.getElementById("add").innerHTML += srcTable; // note append is += 
    return false; // stop the click
  }
}
```

**jQuery version**:

[<kbd>**Live Demo**</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/r2C5q/)

```
$(function() {
  var $skillTable = $("#skilltable").clone(); // make a copy
  $("#addBut").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#add").append($skillTable.clone());
  });
});
```

If you want defaults, set them in the default table

```
<input type="number" name="percentage" min="1" max="100" value="50" />
```

or set them in code:

```
$(function() {
  var $skillTable = $("#skilltable").clone(); // make a copy
  $("#addBut").on("click",function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $newTable = $skillTable.clone();
    $newTable.find('[name="percentage"]').val(50);
    $("#add").append($newTable);
  });
});
```

Comment: dear friend,I am new to stack overflow..i did'nt understand how to accept an answer..can u tell me?

Comment: I solved my problem with jquery version that u told me..but i have another issue that when i entering  values to the form and clicking the link Add new skill i get another form which displays the previous value that i have entered..is there any way to avoid displaying previous value ??

Comment: dear friend, Let me ask u 1 more question?? how can i set default values for the form fields when i click Add new skill? for eg:when i click Add new skill which want to display a form with text boxes contain a default values..i do not want set default values for the form fields by editing html code..i want to set values by applying jquery function on the clone of skill table..

Comment: What values for example?

Comment: for example,percentage of knowledge set to 50

Comment: can i ask u one more question ??

Comment: As you binded value to the number box using jquery,can u make the select box skill contain default option "php" as selected? also if i  have a textarea with name description in my skilltable..i want to set a default content for the text area using jquery... i am new to jquery..can u help me??

Comment: Just continue:    $newTable.find('[name="skill"]').val("php");

Comment: But i had tried this..this was not working...also i could'nt set default content for the textarea in this way...do u have any idea?

Comment: I do not know what your issue is.

Comment: Ask a new question or send the URL to my email address - I am off today now

Answer (score 0):

If you use Jquery try to wrap your code into `$(document).ready` to make sure that your html is loaded..

Next, pay attention to your quote, I think you have to use single quote first since you use double quote in your HTML tags like this:

`document.getElementById('add').innerHTML='<html><body><table> ...  </table>     </body></html>'`